# Finding the best way to do a nato phoetic alphabet converter

Tags: java, android

```
public void NATOConverter(String name){
        String [] words = {"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel"
        , "India", "Juliett", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra",
        "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "Xray", "Yankee", "Zulu"};
        for (int i = 0;i< name.length();i++){
            switch (name.charAt(i)){
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                    break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hello guys I just wanted to ask if there is an easier way to try and get the input from an edit text and convert each letter to one of my array values im struggling to think of an approach I can take any suggestions? I'm stuck not sure what im doing currently is correct

Comment: So your input is a string for which you want to identify the Nato word for each letter? So is your desired output a list of Nato words?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
input
.codePoints()
.mapToObj( this :: wordForCodePoint )
.toList()
```

And, that `wordForCodePoint`  method:

```java
if ( codePoint >= 65 && codePoint <= 90 ) {  // US-ASCII for A-Z (uppercase) characters are code points 65 to 90.
    return NatoConverter.natoWords.get( codePoint - 65 );  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
} else if ( codePoint >= 97 && codePoint <= 122 ) {  // US-ASCII for a-z (lowercase) characters are code points 97 to 122.
    return NatoConverter.natoWords.get( codePoint - 97 );  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
} else {
    return "INVALID CODE POINT: " + codePoint;
}
```

## Details

Apparently you want to produce a series of [NATO phonetic alphabet words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet), one word for each letter of an input string.

### `List.of`

An array would work. But I prefer using a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

In Java 9 and later, we can make an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) by calling [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)).

```java
List< String > natoWords = List.of( "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliett", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "Xray", "Yankee", "Zulu" ) ;
```

### Code point, not `char`

The `char` type in Java is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters supported by Java. So I suggest you make a habit of using Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepoint) integer numbers instead.

We need the code point number for each letter in your input. In the following code we get an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) (a series of `int` numbers, one after another) of each letter’s code point. We convert that stream to a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

```java
List < Integer > codePoints = codePointsStream.boxed().toList();
```

The `.boxed()` call converts `int` primitives to `Integer` objects. Not really important here; come back to this point another day if you are unfamiliar.

Before Java 16, replace `.toList()` with: `.collect( Collectors.toList () )`.

```java
List < Integer > codePoints = codePointsStream.boxed().collect( Collectors.toList () );
```

We need a collection of our resulting words. We make an empty list, pre-sized to the number of Unicode characters in our input.

```java
List < String > result = new ArrayList <>( codePoints.size() );
```

Loop our input of code points. For each, test if that code point is an uppercase US-ASCII letter A-Z or a lowercase a-z. If neither, we throw an exception as a way of signaling an error condition.

### From code point to index number

For each code point, we can cleverly convert that number to an index number we need to retrieve from our master list of NATO words. The index numbers for a `List` use the annoying zero-based counting. So we need zero for the first, one for the second, and so on. We get such a number by subtracting the code point number for `A` or `a`, either 65 or 97. For example:

- For `A`, we subtract 65 from 65 to get `0`, the index we need to get "Alpha" from the list.
- For `B`, we subtract 65 from 66 to get `1`, the index we need to get "Bravo" from the list.

```java
for ( Integer codePoint : codePoints ) {
    if ( codePoint >= 65 && codePoint <= 90 ) {  // US-ASCII for A-Z (uppercase) characters are code points 65 to 90.
        String word = NatoConverter.natoWords.get( codePoint - 65 );  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
        result.add( word );
    } else if ( codePoint >= 97 && codePoint <= 122 ) {  // US-ASCII for a-z (lowercase) characters are code points 97 to 122.
        String word = NatoConverter.natoWords.get( codePoint - 97 ); // Annoying zero-based index counting.
        result.add( word );
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Encountered non-ASCII code point: " + codePoint );
    }
}
```

Lastly, we return an unmodifiable list of our resulting NATO words. We call [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) to produce a copy of our modifiable list.

```
return List.copyOf( result ); // Return unmodifiable list.
```

Pull that code all together.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class NatoConverter {
    private static List < String > natoWords = List.of( "Alpha" , "Bravo" , "Charlie" , "Delta" , "Echo" , "Foxtrot" , "Golf" , "Hotel" , "India" , "Juliett" , "Kilo" , "Lima" , "Mike" , "November" , "Oscar" , "Papa" , "Quebec" , "Romeo" , "Sierra" , "Tango" , "Uniform" , "Victor" , "Whiskey" , "Xray" , "Yankee" , "Zulu" );

    public List < String > convert ( String input ) {
        IntStream codePointsStream = input.codePoints();
        List < Integer > codePoints = codePointsStream.boxed().toList();  // Before Java 16, replace `.toList()` with: .collect( Collectors.toList () )
        List < String > result = new ArrayList <>( codePoints.size() );
        for ( Integer codePoint : codePoints ) {
            if ( codePoint >= 65 && codePoint <= 90 ) {  // US-ASCII for A-Z (uppercase) characters are code points 65 to 90.
                String word = NatoConverter.natoWords.get( codePoint - 65 );  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
                result.add( word );
            } else if ( codePoint >= 97 && codePoint <= 122 ) {  // US-ASCII for a-z (lowercase) characters are code points 97 to 122.
                String word = NatoConverter.natoWords.get( codePoint - 97 ); // Annoying zero-based index counting.
                result.add( word );
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException( "Encountered non-ASCII code point: " + codePoint );
            }
        }
        return List.copyOf( result ); // Return unmodifiable list.
    }
}
```

Write a little app to call that code.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.List;

public class App2 {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        NatoConverter natoConverter = new NatoConverter();
        List < String > result = natoConverter.convert( "Basil" );
        System.out.println( result );
    }
}
```

Or, more compactly.

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class App2 {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println(
                new NatoConverter().convert( "Basil" )
        );
    }
}
```

We get these results:

> [Bravo, Alpha, Sierra, India, Lima]

### Streams, lambdas, & method references

After you become familiar with streams, lambdas, and method references, you could rewrite that converter class to something like this.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.List;

public class NatoConverter {
    private static List < String > natoWords = List.of( "Alpha" , "Bravo" , "Charlie" , "Delta" , "Echo" , "Foxtrot" , "Golf" , "Hotel" , "India" , "Juliett" , "Kilo" , "Lima" , "Mike" , "November" , "Oscar" , "Papa" , "Quebec" , "Romeo" , "Sierra" , "Tango" , "Uniform" , "Victor" , "Whiskey" , "Xray" , "Yankee" , "Zulu" );

    public List < String > convert ( String input ) {
        return List.copyOf(
                input
                        .codePoints()
                        .mapToObj( this :: wordForCodePoint )
                        .toList()
        );
    }

    public String wordForCodePoint ( int codePoint ) {
        if ( codePoint >= 65 && codePoint <= 90 ) {  // US-ASCII for A-Z (uppercase) characters are code points 65 to 90.
            return NatoConverter.natoWords.get( codePoint - 65 );  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
        } else if ( codePoint >= 97 && codePoint <= 122 ) {  // US-ASCII for a-z (lowercase) characters are code points 97 to 122.
            return NatoConverter.natoWords.get( codePoint - 97 );  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
        } else {
            return "INVALID CODE POINT: " + codePoint;
        }
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/eiqQP8).

> [Bravo, Alpha, Sierra, India, Lima]

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Regarding my use of "pre-sized", that wording seems to me to sum up the behavior of setting initial capacity on an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Returning an unmodifiable list is a good practice in my opinion. The calling programmer can decide if she/he wants a mutable list or not, but immutable is a safer default.  So I make a habit of doing `return List.copyOf( whateverList );`. Better for the calling programmer to make an conscious explicit choice on mutability, but passing my returned unmodifiable list to the constructor of a new `List`. The benefit of safety outweighs the negligible cost of creating a new list in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String NATOConverter(String name)
{
    String [] words =
        { "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo",
                "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliett",
                "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar",
                "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango",
                "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "Xray", "Yankee", "Zulu"
        };
    
    String output = "" ;
    
    for( int i = 0 ; i < name.length() ; ++i )
    {
        if( name.charAt(i) == ' ' )
        {
            output += "(space) " ;
        }
        else
        {
            int utf8 = name.toUpperCase().charAt(i) ;
            output += ( words[utf8 - 65]  + " " ) ;
        }
    }
    
    return output.substring(0, output.length()-1 /*remove last space*/ ) ; 
}
```

Comment: Hi there im getting this error   Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static final Map<Character, String> WORDS = Stream.of(
    "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel" ,
    "India", "Juliett", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa",
    "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey",
    "Xray", "Yankee", "Zulu")
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word.charAt(0), Function.identity()));

public static String NATOConverter(String name){
    return name.toUpperCase().chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> WORDS.get((char)c))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

And

```
System.out.println(NATOConverter("Hello World"));
```

output:

```
Hotel Echo Lima Lima Oscar Whiskey Oscar Romeo Lima Delta
```

Comment: I don't even care about how much overhead that takes. That is awesome.